# Смена фото на карточке товара при ховере

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть каталог товаров. Нужно сделать, чтобы при ховере на карточку какого-либо товара, у этого товара раз в секунду менялись фото и под фото была шкала, которая тоже перемещалась при смене фото. Количество фото может быть произвольным, может быть одно, тогда фото не должно меняться, а может быть и 10 фото. Как такое реализовать?

Answer (score 2):

```js
var width = 130;

var list = document.body.querySelector('ul');
var liArr = document.body.querySelectorAll('li');
var tdArr = document.body.querySelectorAll('td');

var position = 0,
  count = 0;

tdArr[0].style.background = 'black';

document.body.querySelector('.images').addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
  mouseOut = true;
});

document.body.querySelector('.images').addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  mouseOut = false;

  if (mouseOut || count == liArr.length - 1) {
    clearTimeout(run);
  }

  var run = setTimeout(() => {

    if (count < liArr.length - 1 && !mouseOut) {
      position -= width;
      list.style.marginLeft = position + 'px';

      tdArr[count].style.background = 'white';
      tdArr[count + 1].style.background = 'black';
      count++;
    }

  }, 1000);

});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.carousel {
  position: relative;
  width: 138px;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: lightgray;
}

.carousel img {
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  display: block;
}

.gallery {
  width: 130px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.gallery ul {
  height: 130px;
  width: 9999px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  transition: margin-left 250ms;
  font-size: 0;
}

.gallery li {
  display: inline-block;
}

table {
  width: 138px;
}

table td {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="gallery">
    <ul class="images">
      <li><img src="https://js.cx/carousel/1.png"></li>
      <li><img src="https://js.cx/carousel/2.png"></li>
      <li><img src="https://js.cx/carousel/3.png"></li>
      <li><img src="https://js.cx/carousel/4.png"></li>
      <li><img src="https://js.cx/carousel/5.png"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: В общем решение хорошее. Единственное - надо отменять установленный `setTimeout` при уходе мышки с `.images`.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko, поправил :)

Comment: Надо бы еще var run вынести на глобальный уровень. И оформить все в IIFE или в модуль. А в целом здорово - лови плюсик.

Comment: Интересное решение, но есть проблема. Все это работает только при четко заданных размерах контейнера и картинок в нем. Но если у нас родительский контейнер резиновый с меняющейся шириной при изменении размеров экрана, то подгонять размеры дочерних элементов становится довольно проблематично. И размер смещения слайда тоже становится трудно предугадать

Comment: @СеменСеменович у вас был вопрос по реализации смене слайдов при ховере. Размеры контейнеров и картинок к этому вопросу не относится.